# Div doesn't start on first element on overflow

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, scroll, overflow

I have a `div` that wraps a number of `p` and `anchor` tags when rendered and its using `overflow:auto` to allow scrolling down.

The issue is that it's already scrolled down and doesn't start from the first child when rendering using `map` on react.

Somehow looks like it automatically focused on the `anchor` tag, when I removed the `anchor` tag and replaced it with `span` tag, it `solved` the issue.

Any ideas why it's happening?

Seems like when rendering it automatically got focused on the anchor tag and that's why the scrollbar doesn't start on initial position which is top.

This is a rough pseudocode of the logic and using `Trans` from `react-i18next` to render the html elements

```
<div>
  return array.map((url) => {
    if p tag => return p tag
    if a tag => return a tag
  });
</div>
```

Comment: Kindly share your code for better understanding of the issue

Comment: @AbinThaha Hi, thanks for commenting. I have updated the post, and only using pseudocode as the html is kinda long, but that's what it does.

Comment: With the code provided, I can't say what the actual issue is. But normally there will be a focus to the a tag. Instead you can do one thing, you can create a `ref` to the wrappper and make it scroll to the top after rendering (componentDidMount())

Comment: @AbinThaha The actual issue is that, the elements are rendered on a modal.
This is hidden at first, but when I open the modal, the anchor tag is already focused even before clicking. Not sure why it's happening, and the scroll position is aligned with the focused anchor tag instead of the start of the div.

Comment: Ok, so probably the componentWillReceiveProps would execute each time you open the modal, right ?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.